# Load User Details from Username

Tags: spring-security, ldap, grails-2.0

I've got a domain-class with a user reference:

```
class MyThing {
    MyUser createdBy
    //...
```

And with using the Spring Security plugin, I have a fairly [basic Person class setup](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.1%20Person%20Class) except I'm trying to obtain the user's email address from reference. Using `springSecurityService.principal` works great but *only* for the currently logged in user.

How can I get the user's email address?

If I can't simply "lookup" by username reference, then is it possible to extend my Person class to acquire email address from the LDAP plugin and save to the database?

Comment: I may not have understood your question completely. Spring security stores only the logged in user details in the http session. If you want to find out the details of other users then you need to retrieve from the database/ldap yourself from username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by first adding an email property to my Person class.

```
class MyUser {
    String username
    String email
```

Then by using a ldap template attributes map, I was able to pull the email as well as the username.

```
tokens.add(attributes.get("sAMAccountName").get().toString());
tokens.add(attributes.get("mail").get().toString());
```

From there it was just getting the property `createdBy.email`